# Laravel returning a 404 on an image

Tags: angularjs, rest, laravel, laravel-4

This should be fairly simple though it is completely stumping me.

I have a backend Laravel installation running on localhost:8000

I have a front end Angular app running on localhost:9001.

I have some 'static' images I have included in my seed data (eg. 
'1', 'user.png'), these images are being rendered perfectly in my front end (they are also served from the exact place my image uploads are going).

The URL I am currently serving images from is `http://localhost:8000/images/{filename}`

I can upload images from the front to the back end and they appear in the DB and the image is being put in the filesystem, I'm populating the correct URL in my front end (as evidenced by the previous URL).

My uploaded images are not being shown.

In my logs I am getting:

```
  [2015-01-20 18:13:49] local.ERROR: NotFoundHttpException Route: http://localhost:8000/images/j249ae747ce28c317e02f1fb6d0a10c3.jpg [] []
[2015-01-20 18:13:49] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException'
```

I tried a method in my routes file, but couldnt see why, when I am already serving some images already?

I have also set all permissions to 755 on my /images folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow every bit of multi-system interaction you have going on, but I'd drop back to first HTTP principles.

Try accessing the image URL directly.

```
http://localhost:8000/images/j249ae747ce28c317e02f1fb6d0a10c3.jpg
```

If the error in your browser (or your logs, if you're not developing with `debug` set to `true`) is

> local.ERROR: NotFoundHttpException Route: http://localhost:8000/images/j249ae747ce28c317e02f1fb6d0a10c3.jpg

This means your web server couldn't find a file at `images/j249ae747ce28c317e02f1fb6d0a10c3.jpg`, and handed the request to Laravel.  This means you need to figure out why your webserver can't see the file.

Assuming you're serving `index.php` from the `public` folder

1. Do you have a `public/images/j249ae747ce28c317e02f1fb6d0a10c3.jpg` file?
2. Are you **sure**?  Copy and paste the path into terminal and to a `ls public/images/j249ae747ce28c317e02f1fb6d0a10c3.jpg` to make sure your brain isn't missing some subtle case issue
3. Are any errors showing up in your web server's logs (not Laravel's)
4. Can you create a text/html file in the images folder and serve it?  If not, then you may not be pointing your web server at the folder you think you are.

Something like

```
http://localhost:8000/images/test.txt
http://localhost:8000/images/test.html
```

Some first principles debugging like that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: yeah, first thing i tried was pasting the direct link in the browser, it can find the ones i put in there myself, but cant find the ones that laravel put in, leadig me to think "permissions".

Its worth noting i am storing these image outside my public folder.

when I paste in the absolute path eg. localhost/images/image.png it shows me the placeholder image icon, not a blank page. Just a blank image.

I should note,pasting the url renders the image for the images i put in the folder myself, also, the images do exist

Comment: ive marked this correct, as, i was being a dummy in that the images were trying to be served from my public folder, which already had the two images in question in it, i changed the upload path to public and it worked.

Comment: @fr0s1yjack If that makes you a dummy then every web developer and programmer in the world is a dummy :)

Answer (score 3):

```
rm public/storage
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan storage:link
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you haven't generated a url for your uploaded image

Try accessing your url like this

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/images/j249ae747ce28c317e02f1fb6d0a10c3.jpg
```

To generate the above url

Add this method `\Storage::disk('public')->url();` method in your controller.This method accesses the `public` disk array which is found in `Config\filesystems.php` and it generates a url in the following format

```
    http://localhost:8000/storage/images/j249ae747ce28c317e02f1fb6d0a10c3.jpg
```

For example the method below stores the image in the image folder and generates the url of the image path.

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['image'=>'file|image|max:5000']);
    $imageProfile = new ImageProfile();
    if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid())
    { 
        $image = $request->file('image')->store('images');
        $imageProfile->image_profile_url = \Storage::disk('public')->url($image);
        $imageProfile->save()
    }
    return response()->json($imageProfile,200);
}
```

The code returns a Json response below

```
{
    "id": 13,
    "image_profile_url ": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/images/cxlogqdI8aodERsmw74nmEx7BkxkWrnyJLMH7sFj.jpeg",
    "updated_at": "2020-01-13 16:27:37",
    "created_at": "2020-01-13 16:27:37",
}
```

Try to copy the url and test it in postman.

Visit the link to learn more about Laravel file storage
[Laravel File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
laravel 8
```

Controler function

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'site_title' => 'required',
            'logo_image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
         ]);


        $input['logo_image'] = time().'.'.$request->logo_image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->logo_image->move(public_path('images'), $input['logo_image']);


        $input['site_title'] = $request->site_title;
        //dd($input);
        Site_settings::create($input);


        return back()->with('success','Image Uploaded successfully.');
    }
```

blade view

```
 <td>
              <img src="{{ url('/images/').'/'.$site_settings->logo_image ?? '' }}" alt="" width="250px" height="auto">
            </td>
```